# Android onTouchEvent calls multiple times when communicating with different thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, touch

I am communicating with my Renderer class on a different thread to pass in touch actions using the `queueEvent( new Runnable() )` function. It works well with ACTION_DOWN and prints out ACTION_DOWN on the log **once**. But if I try it with ACTION_UP I get it **multiple times**

SurfaceView.java:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent( final MotionEvent event ){
        if( event != null ){
            queueEvent(
            new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    renderer.reportEvent( event );
                }
            });

            return true;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent( event );
    }
```

Renderer.java

```
public void reportEvent( MotionEvent event ){
        if( event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ){
            Log.d( "DEBUG","ACTION_DOWN" );
        }
        if( event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ){
            Log.d( "DEBUG", "ACTION_UP" );
        }
    }
```

Testing this out on a Galaxy S4 I simply press and release for 1 second the screen and get the following in Log:

```
ACTION_DOWN
ACTION_UP
ACTION_UP
```

And sometimes I get it three times:

```
ACTION_DOWN
ACTION_UP
ACTION_UP
ACTION_UP
```

My rendering thread goes to sleep to keep a steady 30 fps. Could this be the issue?
What is going on? Also what are the boolean return statements for?

**[edit]**
I just tried removing the Thread.sleep in the Renderer thread and it still doesn't work.

Comment: In the reportEvent method, try to log the event.getAction() in the else case to see if there are some other events happening besides up and down. You can then check on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_CANCEL to see what these numbers are according to the constants. This might lend some more information.